# Error _this.props.childcall is not a function. (In '_this2.props.childcall()' is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I have 2 component parent(LoginScreen) and a child(SignupSection). Child component have onClick button. When user click button I need to fire childcall() function from the parent component and this is not working for me. I get this Error

```
_this.props.childcall is not a function.
(In '_this2.props.childcall()' is undefined)
```

[image]

I have the following code:

Parent

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Wallpaper from './Wallpaper';
import SignupSection from './SignupSection';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
   }

   childcall()
   {
     alert("hello , this call from child component");
   }

   render() {
     return (
      <Wallpaper>
      <SignupSection 
        childcall ={this.childcall.bind(this)} 
      />
      </Wallpaper>
      );
    }
   }
```

Child

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';


export default class SignupSection extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    }
    componentWillMount()
    {

    }

    render() {
       return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}  onPress={()=>this.props.childcall()}>Create Account</Text>
           <Text style={styles.text}>Forgot Password?</Text>
          </View>
       );
    }
 }
```

Comment: you code works here https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/quiet-truffles

Comment: do the parent and child component has to be on the same .js file @JuniusL. its not working for me im getting the error above

Comment: can you move your project to snack, and share a link for it.

Comment: @JuniusL  here is the link https://snack.expo.io/@amerbearat/borroup

Comment: it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are rendering the function instead of passing it as a prop.

You are passing inside children prop

```
<SignupSection>
  childcall={this.childcall} 
</SignupSection>
```

change it to

```
<SignupSection childcall={this.childcall} />
```

Comment: @VincentD'amour where is it being passed?

Comment: @JuniusL. `<SignupSection 
        childcall ={this.childcall.bind(this)} 
      />` I might be missing something, but this is the code in the question